# Difference between set of strings doesn't work

Tags: python, string, set, difference

First of all thanks for the help, I'm trying to fix this problem for days.

File myStopWords.txt:

```
è
ad
più
a
b
c
17
```

My code:

```
stopWord = set(open("<...>/myStopwords.txt").read().split("\n"))
oldWords = set(["a","b","ad", "è", "più","17","horse"])

print( oldWords.difference(stopWord) )
```

Results:

```
{'horse', 'ad', 'più', 'è'}
```

Why aren't `"ad"`, `"è"`, `"più"` subtracted from the `set`?

The result should be `{horse}`.

Comment: What does `print(stopWord)` give?

Comment: `set(open("<...>/myStopwords.txt").read().split("\n"))` isn't the best way to read your file. I'd suggest to use `{l.strip() for l in f}` with f opened with a `with open(xxx) as f` block

Comment: exactly my thoughts - there is probably somthing wrong with how your strange words are extraced from the txt document

Comment: Denziloe, this is print(stopWord) output:
{'c', 'piÃ¹', 'ad', 'b', '17', 'a', 'ï»¿Ã¨'}

Comment: Jean-François Fabre now i try

Comment: I'm recognizing a BOM header somewhere ... check your text file with a hex editor. Due to the encoding the strange words (not ASCII) have a different encoding.

Comment: There's your problem then @LucaSquadrone, the file isn't being read properly. As Jean says, this is probably an encoding problem. If you can control it, make sure the text file is saved using UTF-8. And read the file using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. As suggested in previous comments, this is the solution:

1) Convert the text file in UTF-8.

2)

```
fname = '<...>/myStopwords.txt'

with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

stopWord = [x.strip() for x in content] 


oldWords = set(["a","b","ad", "è", "più","17","horse"])
print( oldWords.difference(stopWord) )
```